# Determine if the sequence $a_n=n-\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+3}$ converges or diverges. If it converges, find the limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Determine if the sequence converges or diverges. If it converges, find the limit.

$a_n=n-\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+3}$

Solution:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+3})
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-\sqrt{n^2+4n+3}) \\[6px]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-\sqrt{n^2+4n+3})\cdot\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+4n+3}}{n+\sqrt{n^2+4n+3}} \\[6px]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2-(n^2+4n+3)}{n+\sqrt{n^2+4n+3}} \\[6px]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-4n-3}{n+\sqrt{n^2+4n+3}} \\[6px]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-4n-3)/n}{(n+\sqrt{n^2+4n+3)/n}} \\[6px]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-4-\frac3n}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac4n+\frac{3}{n^2}}} \\[6px]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-4-0}{1+\sqrt{1+0+0}}=-2
\end{align}

I just don't understand how that division inside the square root was made and why we can use in this case, and also why divide by $n$ if we have $n^2$ in the denominator?

Comment: I just reformatted for clarity, without modifying the formulas, except adding parentheses where necessary in the first three formulas.

Comment: N^2 inside a square root is really only n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong step: in the fifth line you should have, in the denominator,
$$
(n+\sqrt{n^2+4n+3})/n
$$
that you can rewrite as
$$
1+\frac{\sqrt{n^2+4n+3}}{n}=
1+\frac{\sqrt{n^2+4n+3}}{\sqrt{n^2}}=
1+\sqrt{\frac{n^2+4n+3}{n^2}}=
1+\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}}
$$

Comment: Why not consider $n^2$ as the greatest power in the denominator?

Comment: @KayodêVital  Because $n^2$ is inside the square root.  $\sqrt{n^2} = |n|$.  Since $n \geq 0$, $|n| = n$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

$$n+2 - \sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 3}$$

$$\left[\sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 4} - \sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 3}\right] \times \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 4} + \sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 3}}{\sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 4} + \sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 3}}$$

$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 4} + \sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 3}}.$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n - \sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 3}$$

$$= \lim_{n\to\infty} ~\left\{ ~\left[~n - (n+2) ~\right] + \left[~\left( ~n+2 ~\right) - \sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 3} ~\right] ~\right\}$$

$$= \lim_{n\to\infty}  ~\left\{ ~[-2] + 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 4} + \sqrt{n^2 + 4n + 3}}  ~\right\} = -2.$$

Answer (score 0):

The calculations simplify if we substitute $k:= n+2.$ Then $$a_n+2=k-\sqrt{(k-1)(k+1)}\\ =k-\sqrt{k^2-1}={1\over k+\sqrt{k^2-1}}$$ Hence $$0\le a_n+2\le {1\over k}={1\over n+2}$$ Thus $\lim_n(a_n+2)=0$ and $\lim a_n=-2.$